# How to construct multilevel menu using CSS only?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem in my CSS. I am creating a vertical menu but my problem is I don't know how to align the second level of categories, with the first. This is also a problem going from the second level to a third level; it also align to the parent level.

My format is like this:

```
Parent 1
   - Second Level 1
      - Third Level 1
      - Third Level 2
      - Third Level 3
Parent 2
   - Second Level 2
      - Third Level 1
      - Third Level 2
      - Third Level 3
```

Here's my desired output:

[image]

Here's my CSS:

```
#category-navigation ul ul { display: none }
#category-navigation ul li:hover > ul { 
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    top: 20px;
    left: 15%;
    z-index: 4;
    width: 30%;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #CCC;
}

#category-navigation ul.parent { 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
    padding: 7px 0px;
}

#category-navigation ul.parent li { 
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
   padding: 7px 0px; 
}
```

Here's the fiddle of my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/rochellecanale/4fh680uv/8/

How do I fix the alignment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should give the `li` elements in the first layer `position: relative`. That way, the positioning of the child `ul` elements is relative to the `li` elements.

To position the child `ul` elements next to the `li` elements, you then could give them

```
top: 0px;
left: 100%;
```

I [updated the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4fh680uv/9/) accordingly. Please note that this needs some additional tweaking to look *really good*, but I will not do all the work for you.

Comment: Thanks sir, I am really poor in css. :)

Comment: Even your html isnt perfect. Please follow the correct syntax while closing the tags.

Comment: Ok Im sorry for that. :)

Comment: I have modified the code and added some css. Check this link http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYZvyQ

Comment: ^ Goodjob. I was just going to point out how bad his mark-up is 

`<li> <a href="http://">Women's Shoes</li></a>`

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this updated code

```
    #category-navigation ul li{position:relative; width: 100%; display: inline-block;}
    #category-navigation ul ul { display: none; }
    #category-navigation ul li:hover > ul { 
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #F5F5F5;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
        z-index: 4;
        width: 100%;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #CCC;
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain what you've changed, and why that achieves what the asker wanted?